# Huh?!.. event.localX retains "proportions" on scaled Sprite?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, scaling

I planned to arrange simple progress bar for my media player, drawing a colored rectangle and then changing it's width property as needed. Visually it looks ok - scales nicely (I could not draw it with zero width, so I assigned minimal value of 0.1).

Real problem is different though, and seems very weird, or at least absolutely non obvious. Since I need to monitor user clicks on that progress bar, to support seek operation in media stream, I thought - I would detect click event, take x coordinate as an offset from parent DisplayObject, recalculate into time and make a seek. Now it turns out, that event.localX doesn't really "scale" along with the Sprite. As I said the most right x coordinate for the progress bar initially is 0.1, and it stays that way (!) no matter how wide will the actual bar become - 5, 100, 1000. If you click the most right pixel of the bar, it will be - 0.1!

Huh?..

I obviously do something wrong. Maybe there is a method, like - refreshCoordinates() or something? What is it?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding why this happens is very important to understanding how Flash works. The key is to realize that every display object has its own coordinate system, and when your scope is inside that system it doesn't matter if the object itself is rotated, scaled, etc. If you live inside the bar graphic, all you know is that the graphic is 0.1 pixel wide, and that a click occurred on the right border. You have no idea whether the display object you live in has been stretched or transformed somewhere up the hierarchy. That's why the event property you're looking at is called `localX` - it tells you where the click occurred *locally*, within that display object.

This is why, in this situation, it's very common to make the bar graphic 100 pixels wide, and then resize it however you want on the stage. If the graphic is internally 100px, and you detect clicks within that scope, then you can treat `localX` like a percentage. And if you then redesign the page and change the visual width of the bar, you don't have to touch the code.

Incidentally, if you want to transform a location from one coordinate system to another, just use `localToGlobal` and `globalToLocal` together. That is:

```
var localToThis:Point = new Point( someX, someY );
var globalToStage:Point = localToGlobal( localToThis );
var localToParent:Point = parent.globalToLocal( globalToStage );
```

(Or another way to fix your problem would be to simply capture the click events further up the display hierarchy, where the bar really is 100px wide, rather than inside the graphic where it isn't.)

One final note: don't get in the habit of making graphics 0.1 pixels wide. With values that are related to rendering, like `x`, `rotation`, and so on, Flash sometimes rounds things off for performance reasons, below sizes that are visually distinguishable. Just make the object 100px or whatever, and transform it down to as small as you like.

Comment: "...simply capture the click events further up the display hierarchy".. ah.. do they bubble? I tried to bubble my custom event and couldn't. Or do the default events, like mouse click bubble and custom - not?

Comment: I thought that tip about 100px and percentage was brilliant. But I guess it will work properly only when one scales that bar down, not - up, 'cause otherwise pixels will get "stretched" and one will sometimes get too wide interval for let's say 10% point. I do not recalculate localX into the percentage and then into time, I get the time directly.

Comment: Yes, most input events bubble through the display list - but there are some caveats, so you might want to google a tutorial on AS3 event bubbling. For the other comment, I don't quite follow what you mean, but what I described works the same whether a clip is stretched or shrunk.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this has something to do with Global vs Local co-ordinates. Why don't you try `LocalToGlobal` method? [Here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/06/22/understanding-as3-localtoglobal-method/) is an article which explains the function.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. That was it. Looks like transformed objects tend to retain initial dimensions and coordinate system internally. Is it that good idea to override default event properties with these "unexpected" values? Why not to have a special function to get this, rather then having special function to get ones that one might expect in first place... Ah... waste... Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, looks like there is another big twist in this thing. Using localToGlobal you do not get localX translated in "real" value, you just get a global coordinate and then one might need to subtract offsets...

Comment: Yeah, you need to do that. I am pretty sure there is API support which gets stage.GlobalX or something similar. You might want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across this before but it sure looks weird. I was able to reproduce the problem drawing through the `graphics` object and then changing the sprite width.

Anyway, there's a simple workaround. Draw your bar with the max width upfront and then scale it. Something like this:

```
var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();

sp.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
sp.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,30);
sp.graphics.endFill();
sp.scaleX = 0;

sp.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,handleEnterFrame);
sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleClick);
addChild(sp);

function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(e.localX);
}

function handleEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    sp.scaleX += 0.01;
}
```

I'm using an enter frame to simulate progress, but the point is that you update the `scaleX` instead of the `width` of the sprite to reflect the progress.

Comment: Hmm... initially my thought was - "what an awesome workaround!", but... does it actually fixes the problem? Won't you just get an always 200 on your very right pixel, instead of 0.1?.. By the way what is the difference between changing scaleX and width? Notation? I couldn't find any functional difference when I was experimenting.

Comment: @jayarjo. I do think it fixex the problem. Have you tried it? Don't know why setting width doesn't work, really. I've always used scale for progress bars and such and never had major problems with that (not because I was aware of any problem setting the width; it's just that that's the way I learnt to do it and that's what I'm used to think about, well, scaling objects).